# Insert rowdivider in top of datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a datagridview where I have two kind of content types. Active alarms and handled alarms. I use row.DividerHeight to separate the two types, but when I don't have any active alarms I would like to place the divider at the top of the datagridview, but the property only sets the bottom of the row.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Dividers are meant to divide and at the top there is nothing to divide..

..but if you **really** want to you can add a dummy `Row` at the top and set its `Height` to `0`:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height = 0;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DividerHeight = 2;
```

Of course it is up to you to decide if that is worth it..